# How to store first N strings from a txt file in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to get the first N strings from a txt file, and store them into an array. Right now, I have code that gets every string from a txt file, separated by a space delimiter, and stores it into an array. However, I want to be able to only grab the first N number of strings from it, not every single string. Here is my code (and I'm doing it from a command prompt):

```
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
contents = f.read().split(' ')
f.close()
```

I'm sure that the only line I need to fix is:

```
contents = f.read().split(' ')
```

I'm just not sure how to limit it here to N number of strings.

Comment: You can read a certain number of bytes by using `f.read(N)`, where `N` is the number of bytes read.

Comment: @AustinA But he's not trying to read N bytes, he's trying to read N _words_.

Comment: Are the strings only separated by spaces, i.e. one huge line? Or are they also separated by newlines? Can you post two sample lines? Is N small (like < 100) or large (like 1 million?)

Comment: If you actually have a huge file, especially if it doesn't have any newlines, I suspect the most efficient simple solution would be to `mmap` the file, then it's just `contents = list(islice(re.finditer(r'(.*?)\s', m), n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is really big, but not too big--that is, big enough that you don't want to read the whole file (especially in text mode or as a list of lines), but not so big that you can't page it into memory (which means under 2GB on a 32-bit OS, but a lot more on 64-bit), you can do this:

```
import itertools
import mmap
import re
import sys

n = 5

# Notice that we're opening in binary mode. We're going to do a
# bytes-based regex search. This is only valid if (a) the encoding
# is ASCII-compatible, and (b) the spaces are ASCII whitespace, not
# other Unicode whitespace.
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    # map the whole file into memory--this won't actually read
    # more than a page or so beyond the last space
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

    # match and decode all space-separated words, but do it lazily...
    matches = re.finditer(r'(.*?)\s', m)
    bytestrings = (match.group(1) for match in matches)
    strings = (b.decode() for b in bytestrings)

    # ... so we can stop after 5 of them ...
    nstrings = itertools.islice(strings, n)

    # ... and turn that into a list of the first 5
    contents = list(nstrings)
```

Obviously you can combine steps together, even cramming the whole thing into a giant one-liner if you want. (An idiomatic version would be somewhere between that extreme and this one.)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to stop reading exactly as soon as you've reached the nth word, you pretty much have to read a byte at a time. But that's going to be slow, and complicated. Plus, it's still not *really* going to stop reading after the nth word, unless you're reading in binary mode and decoding manually, and you disable buffering.

As long as the text file has line breaks (as opposed to being one giant 80MB line), and it's acceptable to read a few bytes past the nth word, a very simple solution will still be pretty efficient: just read and split line by line:

```
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
contents = []
for line in f:
    contents += line.split()
    if len(contents) >= n:
        del contents[n:]
        break
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with reading the whole file (assuming it's not memory prohibitive to do so) you can just do this:

```
strings_wanted = 5
strings = open('myfile').read().split()[:strings_wanted]
```

That works like this:

```
>>> s = 'this is a test string with more than five words.'
>>> s.split()[:5]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'string']
```

Answer (score 0):

what about just:

```
output=input[:3]
```

output will contain the first three strings in input